# How can I filter my model on Laravel builder based on the number of relationship that exists on the database

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say hypothetically I have 3 tables `products`, `product_images`, and `variants`, a product can have multiple images or variants. I have a requirement, for a product to be viewable by another user you need to have at least 4 product images and 3 variants, and then they are considered valid. I want to be able to query all the products that are considered valid without pulling out a collection and having to use a model method to filter, How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of going through this trouble, why not make it required the user adds 4 images and 3 variants, then you will only have correct data in your database and you won't have to anything too complicated?

Comment: That has something to do with UX. Let's just say this way is better, probably complicated, but necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` [query builder method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```php
Product::has('images', '>=', 4)->has('variants', '>=', 3)->get();
```